# Genus of orientable surface (interlocked double torus)

Tags: general-topology

On Wikipedia page about [Genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Topology) we can read:

> In simpler terms, the value of an orientable surface's genus is equal
>   to the number of "holes" it has.

See also [Genus g surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_g_surface).

I guess this rule about number of holes holds only for simple n-tori. Am I right?

So simple double torus (see image on wikipedia) has genus 2.

Then the following "interlocked double torus" is of what genus? How we would count the holes?
[image: interlocked double torus]

And the following sum of two perpendicular tori is of what genus?
[image: sum of two perpendicular tori]

Comment: The genus does not depend on the embedding into R^3.

Comment: The more general concept is the [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Topological_definition)

Comment: @user587399: So you mean that in complex projective plane such objects are impossible?

Comment: I mean that the Euler Characteristic and hence the genus is an intrinsic property, therefore “interlocking phenomena” does not affect it, but surgeries like connected sum etc. Does

Comment: So their genus is same as genus of simple double torus, i.e. $2$?

Comment: @user587399: It does not make a sense for me then. If on the one hand "The coffee cup and donut shown in this animation both have genus one" then on the other hand you can not make from coffee cup with two handles (not interlocked) an "interlocked double torus" without crossing the matter itself.

Comment: Well you can, if you consider it in higher dimensional space. The difference is that the homotopy from the donut to the coffee cup can be realized in 3 space. Maybe Think of a “simpler” object like a circle. The circle can be embedded in R^3 in very complicated and interesting ways, giving rise to the rich theory of knots. Two such knots might not be deformable to each other in R^3, but if we pass to through an extra dimension they are. This is somewhat reflected in the fact that the topology of the knots themselves are not that interesting, since they are all topologically a circle.

Comment: Yes you are right, at first sight it looked like orange object cannot be transformed into simple double torus, but now I see it can be. So the orange object has genus 2. The blue object can be transformed into triple torus (if I am not mistaken again) and therefore has genus 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the genus is an intrinsic property does not mean that one's favorite method of counting holes is an intrinsic property. Perhaps, historically or as a teaching method, counting holes can lead us to the genus, which is proved to be intrinsic by the equation 
$$\chi(S)=2-2g
$$ 
and by a separate topological proof that $\chi(S)$ is intrinsic.

So, your guess about that rule is correct: don't bother trying to stretch the idea of "holes" beyond the initial intuition.